# Ruby puts command in modules returning nil

Tags: ruby

i am working though LearnTocodethehardway.com http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex25.html 
On ex25. In the example there is a module that has a bunch of methods that return or print values. The Print_last_word method when supplied with an array of strings just puts nil. it does this even in his example output. My question would then be why?

Comment: puts always returns nil. That's just what it does

Answer (score 3):

To be precise, it doesn't *puts* `nil` - it puts the last word and *returns* `nil`. Here's the example output:

```
>> Ex25.print_last_word(words)
wait.    # <- this is the output
=> nil   # <- this is the return value
```

[`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns `nil`.

**UPDATE**

There seems to be a bug in `print_first_word`:

```
module Ex25
  def Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    word = words.pop(0)
    puts word
  end
end

Ex25.print_first_word(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
#=> nil
```

This is because `["foo", "bar", "baz"].pop(0)` returns an empty array and `puts []` just returns `nil` without printing anything.

A working implementation (in the exercise's style) could look like this:

```
module Ex25
  def Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    word = words.shift
    puts word
  end
end
```

Comment: I know that a method always returns the last line however would not the two outputs be the 1st word and last word via the last two lines of the function. 


`def Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end`

Comment: @ChrisCPO there seems to be a bug in `print_first_word` (not `print_last_word`) - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

To make it more easy to understand:

"puts" never is used for its return value. It is used for its *side effect*  if you wanted a method that would return a word, you would then do something with that word.

```
words = ["apple", "cucumber", "apple"]

def give_me_first_word(array_of_words)
    array_of_words.first
end 

variable_to_be_used_later = give_me_first_word(words)
```

This function would return "apple"(and in this case the variable would be assigned "apple"), but it would puts nothing to the screen. This value would then be used in another program or function.

If you puts a value, you would then not need to return it to any other program as it's already served its purpose. It's actually intuitive because if puts also returned the value, it would be doing two things. The counterpart to "puts" would be "return" that simply returns the value and does not display it to the screen.